# Ram not sufficient when implementing Word embeddings using Gensim on my own corpus

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm trying to use gensim library for word embeddings
I have a data frame with each row corresponding to the text data(like a review)
I first converted each row into a list of words using

```
X_train_list = []
for document in X_train:
    sentences = document.split()
    X_train_list.append(sentences)
```

eg: ['This is a sample sentence'] => ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'sentence']

Then i trained word2vec model using gensim on that data

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(total_data, size= 100, min_count=1)
```

Now when i try to embedd each word into a vector, my 12GB RAM is not sufficient and system gets crashing all the time.

```
train_documents = []
count = 0
for document in X_train_list:
    word_vectors = []
    for word in document: 
        word_vectors.append(model.wv[word])
    train_documents.append(np.concatenate(word_vectors))
    count += 1
```

An help to overcome this issue will be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to collect *all* the word vectors, for *all* the documents, into a *concatenated* vector? (That's not a usual operation, so your motivation in doing it is unclear, and maybe there's a better way to achieve the end result *without* that massive interim expansion.)

Comment: For example, imagine a document of 10 5-letter words. As a list of strings, that'd be about (20*5=) 100 bytes, with some object/list overhead. But if every word is a 100-dimensional vector of `float` numbers (4 bytes each), your concatenation of the 20-words' vectors will be a (20 * 100=) 2000-dimensional vector which takes up (2000*4=) 8000 bytes, 80x more than the original represeation! And documents of 100s or thousands of words will be even more expanded. It's rare to need, or be abke to do anything with, such giant concatenated vectors of thousands of dimensions.

Comment: I got your point @gojmo

Comment: As you said, my approach is wrong and i corrected it.